# Build POST url to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Could someone point me to the right direction here... 
I have a form on a site, and I've got a controller. What I want to do is to post the form with jQuery via url like this :

```
/localhost:1234/something?FirstLast=Somebody&Mail=something@something.com&Phone=something
```

This is the controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostPodrskaRequest(string ImePrezime, string Mail, string Telefon, int OdabranaUlogaId)
{
    try
    {
        var r = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImePrezime) || ImePrezime.Length > 128)
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Ime i prezime mora biti upisano i ne smije sadržavati više od 128 znakova!");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Mail) || (!r.IsMatch(Mail)))
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Neispravna mail adresa!");

        var cnt = this._podrskaService.GetPodrskaContent().First(x => x.Uloga.Id == OdabranaUlogaId);
        this._podrskaService.InsertPodrskaRequest(ImePrezime, Mail, Telefon, cnt.Id, OdabranaUlogaId, this._services.WorkContext.CurrentUser.Id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex, "Handled exception!!!");
        _transactionManager.Cancel();
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message, ex);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Zahtjev uspješno poslan.");
}
```

This is my jQuery ajax function:

```
function submitForm() {
    var params = {
        ImePrezime: $("#Forma").find('input[name="ImePrezime"]').val(),
        Mail: $("#Forma").find('input[name="Mail"]').val(),
        Telefon: $("#Forma").find('input[name="Telefon"]').val()
    }
    var str = param(params);

    greska = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@postUri',
        data: str ,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Prošlo!");
            console.log("[OK] Poruka poslana na @postUri");
            console.log("ImePrezime" + ImePrezime);
            console.log("Mail" + Mail);
            console.log("Telefon" + Telefon);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Nije prošlo! :'( ");
                console.log("[FAIL] Poruka poslana na @postUri");
                console.log("ImePrezime" + ImePrezime);
                console.log("Mail" + Mail);
                console.log("Telefon" + Telefon);
            }



        });

    }
```

Comment: Why do you keep changing your question? You keep invalidating my answer...

Comment: Oh sorry, should I share the new code via comment on your answer?

Comment: Why do you need to share it? If there is no need to, don't post it. The answer would be sufficient then. If the answer doesn't help, comment why. Possibly the answerer will ask for code, but that is often the start of an endless discussion.

Comment: The code is not working, trying to figure out why. My console says ReferenceError: param is not defined

Comment: Just pass in `data: params`.

Comment: The error was in `var str = $.param( params );`

Comment: I know. You don't need that.

Comment: Anyways, I've built the link with params and built link with mixing the C# Razor syntax and jQuery like this `url: '@postUri?' + str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are mixing `GET` with `POST`. When your send your parameters using the URL, it is a `GET` request. If it is send in the body, it is a `POST`.

If you use a `GET` while the server expects a `POST`, you will never get the action through (this is to prevent XSS / CSRF for example).

You have to use [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) instead of `$.get` in order to make it a `POST` request.

---

Regarding your update: you are passing a method into `data`. That is not allowed. Just put in your `var params` which you should prepare before calling `$.ajax`.